# Spring Security @Preauthorize Tag Not Working In Unit Test

Tags: spring-security

(First, I apologize, I can't get more than a single level of indention for my code)

I am attempting to write a unit test to test my service-layer methods. The interface for these service classes are annotated with @Preauthorize:

```
public interface LocationService {

    void setLocationRepository(LocationRepository locationRepository);

    /**
     * Get all Location objects from the backend repository
     * @return
     */

    @PreAuthorize("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    List<Location> getAll();
```

The unit test looks something like this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    admin = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("admin", "admin"));
    user = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("user", "user"));
    // create Mock Repository
    // set up the actual service WITH the repository
    locationService = new LocationServiceImpl();
    locationService.setLocationRepository(locationRepository);
}

@Test(expected = AccessDeniedException.class)
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void testGetAllAsUser() {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(user);
    List<Location> resultList = locationService.getAll();
}
```

Finally, here is the security context from my applicationContext.xml:

```
<!-- Temporary security config. This will get moved to a separate context 
    file, but I need it for unit testing right now -->
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:form-login />
    <security:session-management
        invalid-session-url="/timeout.jsp">
        <security:concurrency-control
            max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </security:session-management>
</security:http>
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="admin" password="admin"
                authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <security:user name="user" password="user"
                authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true" />
```

Unfortunately, the @PreAuthorize tag is being ignored, allowing someone with ROLE_USER to run getAll().

Can anyone help?

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Are you running the unit test with the spring junit runner?
- Are you pointing to the correct spring configuration file for that unit test?
- Have you configured load time weaving for the security aspects?

The line:

```
locationService = new LocationServiceImpl();
```

Creates a new location service, bypassing spring altogether.  If you are using the spring junit runner then you should use @Resource to get the locationService injected so that you are using the spring bean and not just your pojo.

Comment: Good point, I'll fix it to get the LocationService bean straight from the context. I'll also try to figure out if I have the weaving set up, but the code is at work so I can't check it until the morning.

Comment: You don't need to have LTW enabled in order for this to work, but if it's not then you need to make sure that you are calling the method on the spring proxy and not on your impl directly, which is where the latter half of my answer is going.

Comment: Okay, you were right. VERY dumb mistake on my part. I turned around and had Spring autowire the locationService.

Comment: This is exactly how I learned, and it's a lesson I won't soon forget.  Glad it helped.

Comment: Hi,

I am calling method on the Service and including the Service Class in the @ContextConfiguration. However its not working for me and I am using SpringRunner. What will cause Spring to use the AOP proxy for the Service interface that has the PreAuthorize annotation on it  in the unit Test.

Comment: Found the  answer - had to add @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) on the test !!

Comment: The reason is that in my application , this annotation is on my SpringApplication class , however in the JUnit "Test" class I use  @ContextConfiguration to load "ONLY" the service class that I am testing that has the PreAuthorize annotation on it. Hence, the service class is loaded into the JUnit "Test" Application context , however the EnableGlobalMethodSecurity annotation was missing.